# Registering Generic Types using Generic complex type with AutoFac

Tags: c#, generics, autofac

I have a Caching Repository that inherits from the same interface as my data repository.

```
public interface IReadOnlyRepository<T,U>
{
    T Get(U key);
    IList<T> GetAll();
}
```

The caching repository takes in its constructor an IReadOnlyRepository that matches its generic types. With this I'm able to implement code that check if the item is in cache an if not retrieves from database and stores to cache. I'm running into a problem with the registration of this Generic Cache in AutoFac. I have the following code which is breaking right now

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(DomainObjectRepository<,>)).Keyed("iRepoLayer",typeof(IRepository<,>));
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(CacheRepo<,>))
    .As(typeof(IRepository<,>))
    .WithParameters(new List<Parameter>()
    {
        new ResolvedParameter(
            (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IRepository<,>),
            (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveKeyed("iRepoLayer",typeof(IRepository<,>))),
            ...(Other Constructor params)
    }
```

Interface

```
 public interface IReadOnlyRepository<T,U>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the specified item from the repository.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        T Get(U key);

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets all items in the repository
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        IList<T> GetAll();
    }
```

Data Layer implementation

```
   public class ReadOnlyRepository<T,U> :IReadOnlyRepository<T,U> where T:ObjectWithId<U>
    {
       internal ICoreRepository _coreRepository;

        public ReadOnlyRepository(ICoreRepository coreRepository)
        {
            _coreRepository = coreRepository;
        }

       private static Expression<Func<T, object>> _getId = t => t.Id;  

        public T Get(U key)
        {
            return _coreRepository.GetBy(_getId, key);
        }

       public virtual IList<T> GetAll()
       {
           return _coreRepository.GetAll<T>().ToList();
       }
}
```

Caching Layer

```
 public class CacheReadOnlyRepo<T,TId> : IReadOnlyRepository<T, TId> where T :ObjectWithId<TId>
    {
        private IReadOnlyRepository<T, TId> _readOnlyRepo { get; set; }
        protected static readonly string IdKeyPrefix = GetKeyPrefix(o => o.Id);
        protected static readonly string GetAllKey = GetSetCacheKey<T>();
        protected ICoreCachingRepo _coreCachingRepo; 

        public CacheReadOnlyRepo(IReadOnlyRepository<T,TId> readOnlyRepo, CacheEventManager cacheEventManager, ICacheClient cacheClient, ICoreCachingRepo coreCachingRepo)
        {
            _readOnlyRepo = readOnlyRepo;
            _cacheEventManager = cacheEventManager;
            _cacheClient = cacheClient;
            _coreCachingRepo = coreCachingRepo;
        }

        public T Get(TId id)
        {
            var key = GetCacheKey(IdKeyPrefix, id);
 //calls the cache for item and passes method to retreive items if they are not in cache
           return _coreCachingRepo.GetViaCache(_readOnlyRepo.Get, key, id);
        }


        public virtual IList<T> GetAll()
        {

             //calls the cache for item and passes method to retreive items if they are not in cache
            return _coreCachingRepo.GetAllViaCache(_readOnlyRepo.GetAll, GetAllKey).ToList();
        }
}
```

Thank You!

Comment: Could you share interface and class inheritance of what you are trying to register and dependencies of implementations (constructor parameters) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is an implementation of a decorator design pattern. Autofac supports the pattern explicitly.

Here is an article describing the support in details: http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/decorator-support-in-autofac-2-4/

Relevant code snippet adjusted to use your classes:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(ReadOnlyRepository<,>))
   .Named("read-only-repo", typeof(IReadOnlyRepository<,>));

// Register the generic decorator so it can wrap
// the resolved named generics.
builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
    typeof(CacheReadOnlyRepo<,>),
    typeof(IReadOnlyRepo<,>),
    fromKey: "read-only-repo");
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. I apologize I've been busy with other projects and just got a chance to try this solution.